# Custom font-awesome button with content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I would like to have a button that looks like `Log in with [FB]`, wher `[FB]` is font-awesome icon. (Note that this icon appears at the end). For this purpose, this works:

```
= form_tag my_path, :method => :post do
  = button_tag do
    Log in with
    %i.icon-facebook
```

I would like to DRY this up by create a new helper method:

```
  def button_to_with_icon(path, text, button_class, icon)
    form_tag path, :method => :post do
      button_tag(:class => button_class) do
        text
        content_tag :i, "" , :class => icon.to_sym
      end
    end
  end
```

However, the `text` argument does not render in HTML. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: does `text.html_safe` work?

Comment: @omnikron : no, it does not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `button_tag` block will use what's returned there as text. Here you are implicitely returning the `content_tag`, and throwing the text.

You should use `concat` inside your `content_tag` block:

```
button_tag do
  concat text
  concat content_tag(:i, nil, :class => icon.to_sym)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. This works. Do you mind explaining why this works and ckruse's method doesn't work? It seems to me that we are concatenate strings here?

Comment: I think that with @ckruse's you need to call the `html_safe` method. Before I used to use before knowing `concat`, I was building an inner array of tags and text, and at the end calling `inner.join.html_safe`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the return value of `text` simply gets wasted. You have to return a concatenation of both, the `content_tag` and `text`:

```
def button_to_with_icon(path, text, button_class, icon)
  form_tag path, :method => :post do
    button_tag(:class => button_class) do
      text + content_tag(:i, "" , :class => icon.to_sym)
    end
  end
end
```

A ruby method is not ERB :-)

Comment: Hi ckruse: Thanks for reminding me :-). However, `+` haven't work for me yet, because it will force `content_tag` to become a string just like `text`. Is there a way to escape it?